# Ersteller vs Hersteller

Tags: synonym

I have seen both this words, *Hersteller* and *Ersteller* and they seem to mean the same. Which seems kinda weird because they are so similarly written, that often I think it is just a typo.

Is there any special difference between one and the other?

Comment: I'm convinced that *h*-misspellings happen only in Spanish ;) In German nobody would do that, for *h* sounds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hersteller:** widely used, means typically the manufacturer of an industrial product (car, elevator, refrigerator ...)

**Ersteller:** rarely used, can mean author, e. g. of a bug report

Comment: Oh well, I guess then it makes sense (I am a programmer)

Answer (score 4):

You can really translate them one to one:

Hersteller: manufacturer / producer

Ersteller: originator / creator